# Crash on CleverTap - Swift - iOS - [CleverTap generateAppFields]

Tags: ios, swift, clevertap

Came across one issue with respect to CleverTap which is not reproducible. The app crashes even before any of the app entry points are triggered. Put logs on all app entry points to monitor this.

Anybody had similar issues and any solutions tried?

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19e80f020 objc_release + 16
1  CleverTapSDK                   0x106a98aac -[CleverTap generateAppFields] + 1107 (CleverTap.m:1107)
2  CleverTapSDK                   0x106a9a44c -[CleverTap recordAppLaunched:] + 1366 (CleverTap.m:1366)
3  CleverTapSDK                   0x106a9a088 -[CleverTap _appEnteredForeground] + 1325 (CleverTap.m:1325)
4  CleverTapSDK                   0x106a99e5c -[CleverTap _appEnteredForegroundWithLaunchingOptions:] + 1303 (CleverTap.m:1303)
5  CleverTapSDK                   0x106aa68e0 -[CleverTap notifyApplicationLaunchedWithOptions:] + 3283 (CleverTap.m:3283)
6  CleverTapSDK                   0x106a93598 +[CleverTap onDidFinishLaunchingNotification:] + 311 (CleverTap.m:311)
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1897329a0 **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 28
8  CoreFoundation                 0x189732948 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 52
9  CoreFoundation                 0x189731eb0 _CFXRegistrationPost + 440
10 CoreFoundation                 0x189731870 _CFXNotificationPost + 716
11 Foundation                     0x18a9f84bc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64